# I am looking for a developers friendly, simple credit card processing service for a business outside of the US. Any recommendations?

Tags: ecommerce, creditcard

We are located in Israel and suppose to receive payments from all over the world, but mostly from North America and Western Europe.

Can one recommend a developer friendly, reliable and simple service which I can use?

(hint: PayPal is a wrong answer!)

I wish [Stripe](http://stripe.com) were serving customers outside of US, but this is not the case yet.

Comment: May I ask why PayPal is a wrong answer? It's extremly developer friendly compared to many others and it's in EU too. We are currently usinsg it, and many companies in Italy do use it too.

Comment: Closed as per [this meta question](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/627/where-to-buy-whatever-is-this-low-quality)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Moneybookers,

http://www.moneybookers.com/ads/merchant-account/ecommerce-payment-system/

I'm using their services between my different bank accounts since a couple of year and you can trust them. You can even have a Master Card linked to your account.

Hope it help

Comment: just signed up with them, thanks for the recommendation.